# UIWebView crashing when loading URL

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift2

This should be really straightforward but I have no idea why this code is not working. I try to load a basic URL into a `UIWebView` like this:

```
    let string = "www.google.com".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    let url = NSURL(string: string!)

    if let ur = url {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: ur)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

However each time I get this error:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Stepping through it nothing is `nil`. Figured I'd do this just to make sure:

```
    let string = "www.google.com".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

    // unwrap the string
    if let str = string {

        let url = NSURL(string: str)

        // unwrap the url
        if let ur = url {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: ur)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }
```

Which I still get the same crash! If I look at the thread I get this when running on a device:

> 0x656d6c <+68>:  bl     0x6abac4                  ; function signature
>   specialization 1 = Exploded> of
>   Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString,
>   Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)

---

So my `UIWebView` is `nil` somehow...I have everything hooked up correctly? Any ideas
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@penatheboss answers was correct however I wanted to post how I fixed it. My `IBOutlets` were hooked up correctly however my `UIWebView` was always `nil` in my class. Even in `viewDidAppear`.

How I fixed it:

- Cleaned my project
- Quite Xcode
- Deleted the derived data folder
- Reopened project Build

Then it worked fine with the original code I posted. *Talk. About. Annoying.*

Answer (score 1):

The WebView itself must be `nil`. If there is an empty circle to the left of the outlet, reconnect it by dragging and dropping from the view to the outlet.

Comment: You're right but that's really weird. I have everything hooked up correctly...i've updated my question.